# codeigniter: pagination edit query

Tags: sql, codeigniter, pagination

i have my pagination

**Controller:**

```
$this->load->library('pagination', TRUE);
$conf['base_url'] = "http://localhost/projecto/index.php/produto_serv_c/list_produto_serv";
$conf['per_page'] = 10;            
$conf['num_links'] = 5;
$conf['total_rows'] = $this->get_list_m->get_prod_serv()->num_rows();

$this->pagination->initialize($conf);
$cenas = $this->get_list_m->get_prod_serv()->result_array();

$data['query'] = $this->db->get("produto_servico_tbl", $conf['per_page'], $this->uri->segment(3));
```

buy, i  want to do this query:

**Model:**

```
public function get_prod_serv(){
    $this->db->from('produto_servico_tbl');
    $this->db->where('id_empresa', $this->session->userdata('id_empresa'));
    $this->db->order_by('referencia', 'asc');
    $this->db->having('id_empresa', $this->session->userdata('id_empresa'));

    $query = $this->db->get();
    return $query;
}
```

how do I change the pagination query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you forgot to put limit in your code thats y pagination is not working

```
public function get_prod_serv($number, $start){
    $this->db->from('produto_servico_tbl');
    $this->db->where('id_empresa', $this->session->userdata('id_empresa'));
    $this->db->limit($number, $start);
    $this->db->order_by('referencia', 'asc');
    $this->db->having('id_empresa', $this->session->userdata('id_empresa'));

    $query = $this->db->get();
    return $query;
}
```